# Delete - I can't specify target table? While deleting using query

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

```
DELETE FROM wp_posts 
WHERE ID > ( 
    SELECT ID 
    FROM wp_posts 
    WHERE post_title = 'angiegreen') 
        && (post_author = 0 
            OR post_author > ( 
                SELECT ID FROM `wp_users` WHERE user_login = 'angiegreen'));
```

Comment: but i am deleteing the data using this query

Comment: thats why i am asking that question i study that question before but this question answer is not helpfull for me